# Time Machine Backup to Samba Share under Mac OS Lion

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine, smb

In earlier versions of Mac OS you could enable TimeMachine to use Samba-Shares as a Backup-Target using this:

```
defaults write com.apple.systempreferences TMShowUnsupportedNetworkVolumes 1
```

and create a backup image with [this](https://gist.github.com/961550) script.

Sadly Time Machine now says that my drive does not support the necessary AFP protocol.

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suspiciously named Msftguy has written a program that fakes the required AFP features for unsupported volumes.  AFAIK this is currently the only way to use non-AFP volumes with 10.7 lion.  Use at your own risk!

[Details](http://msftguy.blogspot.com/2011/07/lion-time-machine-and-afp-feature-bits.html)

[Executable](https://github.com/msftguy/backupd-afpbits/archives/master)

Answer (score 1):

I used this blogpost as a guide, and it works quite well: http://basilsalad.com/how-to/create-time-machine-backup-network-drive-lion/

The approach is to create an HFS+ drive image on the network drive, mount it using tmutil, then use it with Time Machine.  Since the drive appears to be HFS+, there should be no issue with using older AFP versions or even SMB/Samba on typical NAS drives and Linux servers.

Comment: Links may break rendering your answer unhelpful. Can you please summarize the content of the referenced page in your answer?